# How can I write a compound WHERE condition using documentdb?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "email": "joan.smith@somedomain.com",
  "name": {
    "first": "Joan",
    "last": "Smith"
  }
}
```

How can I write a SQL query that uses a compound comparison against the entire last name?

This is effectively what I'd like to do in the WHERE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHERE c.name.first + " " + c.name.last = "Joan Smith"
```

The "plural" version

```
SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHERE c.name.first + " " + c.name.last 
  IN ("Joan Smith", "Juan Suarez")
```

Both of these queries will run in the Azure Portal without error, but they return empty results.  I have tried wrapping the concatenation in parentheses but this has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Cosmos DB [SQL APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-reference) , if you want to implement concatenation in Cosmos DB SQL, you need to use **||** instead of **+**.

So, please modify your sql as below:

```
SELECT c.id,c.name 
FROM c 
WHERE c.name.first || " " || c.name.last = "Joan Smith"
```

Then you could get the results you want.

[image]

Hope it helps you.